# Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: paginate is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use the express-paginate package, but I'm getting this error:
Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: paginate is not defined

this is my code:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const paginate = require('express-paginate');
// var app = express();
var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    ...
    app.get('/xxx', category.regionIndex);
```

gpmodel.js

```
Gpmodel
        .findAll(values)
        .then(function(gpmodels) {
            // console.log(gpmodels);
            const itemCount = gpmodels.count;
            const pageCount = Math.ceil(gpmodels.count / req.query.limit);
         ...
res.render('category/category.ejs', {
                    gpmodels: gpmodels,
                    seo_asset: seo_asset,
                    pageCount,
                    itemCount,
                    pages: paginate.getArrayPages(req)(3, pageCount, req.query.page)
                });

...
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call one time, use any where.

In `gpmodel.js` define it:

```
const paginate = require('express-paginate');
```